# Is it possible to use \begin{align} in an inline math mode with \displaystyle?

Tags: math-mode, align, inline, displaystyle

Is it possible to use `\begin{align}` in an inline math mode with `\displaystyle`?

Comment: Well, have you tried it? I suspect it will not work, though. `\begin{aligned}` has a better chance of working.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Harald, `\begin{align}` does NOT work, but `\begin{aligned}` works.

Comment: @Seamus, I want to put it in a tabular cell. I notice that inline equations get vertically centered by default in `m{}` type column.

Comment: the align environment cannot be used in math mode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`aligned` is intended for this. But also `align` works if you use `\parbox`:

```
Text $\displaystyle\parbox{2cm}{\begin{align}
x &= 1 \\
y &= 0
\end{align}}$ \quad more text
```

[image]