# How to begin an align environment with an inline equation?

Tags: align, inline

I want to write the following in LaTeX (without the horizontal ruled lines):
[image]
where the equals signs are vertically aligned with each other.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8520/is-it-possible-to-use-beginalign-in-an-inline-math-mode-with-displaystyle/8522#8522) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/how-can-i-write-multi-line-equations-with-alignment-in-inline-math-mode) which both suggest using the `aligned` environment. I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
By the quotient rule, 
\(\begin{aligned}
f'(x)&=\frac{v(x)u'(x)-u(x)v'(x)}{(v(x))^2}\\
&=\frac{(2x-2)(2)-(2x+2)(2)}{(2x-2)^2}\\
&=\frac{4x-4-4x+4}{(2x-2)^2}
\end{aligned}\)
\end{document}
```

But it gave me this [image]
instead of what I wanted.

Is there any way to begin the aligning with an inline equation like what I wrote?

Comment: Use `\begin{aligned}[t]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\(\begin{aligned}
\text{By the quotient rule,}\quad
f'(x)&=\frac{v(x)u'(x)-u(x)v'(x)}{(v(x))^2}\\
&=\frac{(2x-2)(2)-(2x+2)(2)}{(2x-2)^2}\\
&=\frac{4x-4-4x+4}{(2x-2)^2}
\end{aligned}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]